# Probability for a series to converge

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $t_n$ be a random variable in $\{-1,1\}$, with $\text{P}(t_n=1)=\text{P}(t_n=-1)=\frac{1}{2}$. What is the probability that the series
$$
S_\infty=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty
\frac{t_n}{n}$$
converges?

Comment: If they are independent then you have the law of large numbers

Comment: Why does the LLN (about $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n t_i$) apply here (about $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n} t_n$) ?

Answer (score 2):

If $t_n=t_1$ for all $n$ then the probability is $0$. If $t_n$'s are independent then it is $1$ by Kolomogorov's Three Series Theorem. In general it is $0$ or $1$ by Kolmogorov's 0-1 law.